# Where can I buy the Egal-Wohin-Ticket?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

In addition to the 9-Euro ticket, there is another interesting offer on the German railways - the [Egal-Wohin-Ticket](https://www.edeka.de/services/egal-wohin-ticket.jsp), a train ticket which allows one to travel between any two places in Germany for 40 EUR.

I tried to obtain it in one of the Edeka shops in Bremerhaven, but when I asked for it, the cashier gave me a very strange look and said that railway tickets should be purchased at the train station. It was obvious that she had never even heard about this offer. I'm traveling long-distance within a few days and would like to obtain the ticket.

**It could be possible that there are some limitations on where the ticket can be bought or the offer is no longer valid, or the tickets are sold out. If not, where can I really buy the tickets?**

**Edit:**
I tried multiple places where you're supposed to be able to buy these (Marktkauf, Budni, Trinkgut, Nah & gut, EDEKA) and in some Budnis, there were empty places where the tickets used to be saying that they are sold out.

Finally, I was lucky in one of the Niemerszein EDEKAs, but the process of buying the tickets was unexpected - they printed the code on a receipt at the cashier's desk (the one which serves also as info/tobacco/quick desk) instead of having a ready-made card for it.

I bought some and later (Wednesday evening) successfully booked a ticket for Friday morning which would otherwise be about twice as expensive. I wouldn't be so pessimistic about the slots in the trains being sold out - right now there are plenty of people who have the tickets available and I was still able to secure a slot, and with time the number of unused tickets will go down, and they are valid for more than a year.

Comment: did you look at the gift card stand (Geschenkkarten-Ständ), [as suggested by DB](https://www.bahn.de/angebot/aktionsangebote/egal-wohin-ticket), when you were in the shop?

Comment: @mlc This particular shop didn't seem to have one, unlike many other shops I've visited. Or they are not near the cashier desks at Edeka.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

DB has had similar offerings before, and also this time, they make it hard to get and hard to use.

Be aware:

- The tickets are only available in 'participating' Edeka shops and not all Edeka shops. The list of participating shops is not published, nor is there an online function to search for one.
- DB points out, that even participating shops may be sold out and that the offer is only available as a limited number of tickets. They obviously expect you to run around to different Edeka shops or at least call them in advance to ask if they are participating and still have tickets.
- It is not really a ticket as the name suggests, but rather a voucher you can use to later pay for a proper train ticket. There is a limited number of seats on each train for Egal-Wohin-Ticket holders, so even if you have managed to find and buy a voucher, you have no guarantee that you can actually use it to book a ticket for the train you later intend to travel with.
- It is not possible to check if seats are available for a specific train without actually having a voucher code. You have to buy an Egal-Wohin-Ticket first, to then later possibly find out that you can't use it for the trip you have planned.
- And finally, 39.90€ is not necessarily a very good offer for a train ticket in Germany. If you buy your regular ticket a bit in advance and can travel during off-peak hours, you can probably get a cheaper saver fare for most routes. I can for example now get a regular ticket from Munich to Hamburg (almost across the entire country) for 37.90€ if I book 6 days in advance, 27.90€ if I book 8 days in advance and 17.90€ 13 days in advance.

Comment: The "man in seat 61" has complained this appears to be a common strategy: make a certain ticket hard to buy (or unknown), then observe that nobody buys them, then abolish the offer.  Apparently Great Britain has many of those.

Comment: Apparently the Egal-Wohin-Ticket also has Zugbindung, like Sparpreis tickets.

Comment: @gerrit As I already wrote, the 'ticket' is in reality only a voucher. After buying the voucher, you must later use it to pay for a 'real' ticket. You have to exchange it for a real ticket at least two days before travelling and the ticket is only valid for a specific departure. What I mean to clarify is, that you don't have to select a specific departure when you buy the voucher, but when you later exchange it for a real ticket.

Comment: Yes, but as a voucher, apparently you can't buy a ticket with the same conditions as a regular flexible ticket.

Comment: @gerrit No, and the restrictions for tickets bought with an Egal-Wohin-Ticket are even stricter than for a regular saver fare (Sparpreis). The Egal-Wohin-Ticket voucher must be used at least two days in advance to buy a ticket. Sparpreis-tickets can, if seats are still available, be bought even on the same day as you are travelling.

Comment: To add some context: the referenced `17.90€` fares (that I could find) are 19:28 - 6:50 and 00:01-09:30. `off-peak hours` is an understatement. Next-best is `59.90€` 10:55-17:24

Comment: @Robus On September 6th (in 13 days) you can get a 17.90€ ticket for the departure 04:12 with arrival in Hamburg 11:29. Perhaps inconvenient yes, but very cheap and not an overnight train as you claim is required.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo If a train leaving at 04:12 is "perhaps inconvenient", just *what* would you consider to be definitely inconvenient? ;-) I really can't think of a worse departure time than 4 am

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica I consider 'definitely inconvenient' a train arriving to late for an appointment or a train too expensive for my budget. Tickets are of course cheaper on trains with less demand, but there are obviously enough passengers travelling at that time to justify running the train. If you are short on money, why not get up some hours earlier and take a cheap train at 4:12?

Comment: One reason for not taking the 4:12 train is living far away from the railway station, and having no public transport connections available from the accommodation to the railway station before 4:12 (that early). I don't know the details of Munich, but in some places the earliest public transport option which arrives to the main railway station leaves after 4:44.

Comment: @pts Munich has a quite dense network of night buses and trams. I live in the outskirts of Munich and while the departures at night are not as frequent as during the daytime, taking the night bus and connecting with a tram at night to the main station would take me about 40 minutes, while the daytime connections are some 30 to 40 minutes with bus, subway and local train. Most German cities have more or less decent public transport also at night.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica - for Germans and Scotsmen, 4AM is morning.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica if one normally works a night shift and is taking a "day" off for travel, 0412 seems like a perfectly reasonable time to get on a train, while 1612 might be absolutely miserable. ;)

Comment: FWIW, DB is operating connections from Munich to Hamburg departing 3:12, 4:12 and 4:27, all originating in Munich. They are obviously not running these trains because it is funny, but because there are enough passengers who are paying to use the services.